# MSSQL in Latin1, PHP in UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, utf-8, iso-8859-1

We're currently making an PHP application with codeigniter, and we have access to 2 databases, one in UTF-8 (our MySQL) and one in Latin1 (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS in MSSQL), this latin1 database is read-only, we do not have control over it, so we cannot change it.

Our problem then is some latin chars are showing as black diamonds.

We have set the database connection on codeigniter as:

```
'dbdriver' => 'mssql',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci'
```

And our PHP has the following encoding:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
```

And our files are saved as UTF8 as well.

We thought, because latin1 is a subset of utf8 there would be no problem, but black diamonds are showing up.
One solution found is using utf8_encode just before showing the text fetched from MSSQL database, but it looks like XGH, there must be a better way.

So basically the question is how to select and show UTF8 (because php is UTF8) from a database that is in Latin1?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` clause will help to you, try with this.

*Usage example*

> SELECT column FROM test ORDER BY column COLLATE utf8_general_ci ASC

refer this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4395/understanding-the-collate-databasedefault-clause-in-sql-server/

Comment: No, it doesn't work, utf8_general_ci is not known by MSSQL. Maybe it's my db driver? I checked and its mssql freetds.